# Magento Change Message after registration in account

Tags: magento

we want to change message after customer  once registered  in Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
Thank you for registering with ..   to other  my own message.
Currently we are doing this by \app\locale\en_GB\Mage_Customer.csv line number 372  and changing message Thank you for registering with %s with other my own message. but not getting success.
Have anyone idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying is the inline translation, that is also a clean way to do so.If it is not working than first verify the locale you are changing is the correct one i.e is your store locale is choosen to **United Kingdom** then making changes to

> app\locale\en_GB\Mage_Customer.csv

should work.

But it won't work than you always have a choice of changing to the file from where it is rendering the text.
 In the file below

> app\code\core\Mage\customer\controllers\AccountController.php

Find the

`protected function _welcomeCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $isJustConfirmed = false){
}`

In this function you will see the text you want to change.

But don't make changes to the core files,its a bad practice.Override the controller in your local folder and make changes there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,app\locale\en_GB\Mage_Customer.csv  Now this is working for me,we have cache and indexing.